# how to automaticly insert data in excel table from other table

Tags: database, excel

I have xml data feed in excel sheet1 with column:

```
productID, productName, stock, price, categoryCode etc.
```

This xml has only category codes like AXS, JSC and so on. I need to create new column: "categoryName" with category names.

Other xml feed in sheet2 has separate table with category codes in one column and category name in other. like this:

```
categoryCode    categoryName
AXS             ABAX Systems
```

Is it possible to get category name from sheet 2 and automaticly paste in sheet1 in new column with name: categoryName?

XML  has 17k products and 600 category codes. Is it possible to do it automaticly, it should be done many times so manual it is too long.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: btw, this is a standard database action, so it may be easier to use some kind of database management system

Comment: Sorry for my English. yes column. I think it is possible with excel. Database would be good but i do not know how :(

Answer (score 0):

It took time but i found solution. The formula is `=VLOOKUP(F2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$347,2,FALSE)`